# I am getting a critical error after editing a RSVP Template which gave rise to multile events on the same day

Tags: wordpress

I see the multiple events listed in RSVP events but no way to remove them. The error is:
WordPress database error: [Character set 'binary' cannot be used in conjunction with 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci' in call to regexp_like.]
SELECT wp_9scqtd_posts.*, meta_value as sked FROM wp_9scqtd_posts JOIN wp_9scqtd_postmeta ON wp_9scqtd_postmeta.post_id = wp_9scqtd_posts.ID WHERE post_type='rsvpmaker_template' AND BINARY `meta_key` REGEXP '*sked*[A-Z].+' and meta_value AND post_status='publish' GROUP BY wp_9scqtd_posts.ID ORDER BY post_title